# How to get suspend and hibernate option back?

Tags: hibernate

I have a strange problem, I could hibernate my laptop before but for some reason hibernate and suspend doesn't exist at all and error when I close the laptop lid I see the error "failed to suspend".
can someone guide me get the suspend, hibernate options back?

Comment: Any particular OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, the hibernate option can be enabled and disabled from an elevated command prompt using:

```
powercfg -h on
powercfg -h off
```

It can also be automatically disabled if you've run out of disk space. The easiest way to free up some space (assuming Windows again) is to delete your System Restore history.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not showing up in the power settings where you can set it.You can do a system restore, to when the service was working or if that does not work reset to factory settings after backing up everything.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming Windows) these options sometimes disappear if your graphics drivers are corrupted or missing. You check those and see if the options return.